# How do I access one button from a 2D array of buttons? Java JSwing

Tags: java, arrays, select, button

I am trying to create a grid of buttons.
This is my code to create the grid (which works), but if I want to access a single button later on how would I go about doing that?

```
    for(int i = 1; i<= row; i++){
        for( int p=1; p<= col; p++){
           boardPanel.add(new JButton());   
        }
    }
```

Many Thanks

A Clements;

Comment: What type is `boardPanel` ?

Comment: Hmm, any number of ways.  You could save those buttons in an array and access them there.  Or in an EvenListener, call `getSource()` on the Event to find the button that fired the event.  It really boils down to how you want to access the button, i.e. what are your requirements?

Comment: boardPanel is a JPanel

Comment: Basically it's a minesweeper game.
I see that with the actionlistener I need to at least call some form of button first. I just don't know what I could call from this 
e.g buttonName.addActionListener...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question title I'm assuming that you want to be able to access these buttons from a 2d array, but in your code the button is not in an array. If you did something like the following:

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[row][col];
for(int i = 1; i<= row; i++){
    for( int p=1; p<= col; p++){
       buttons[i][p] = new JButton();
       boardPanel.add(buttons[i][p]);   
    }
}
```

Then you are maintaining a 2d array that contains references to the buttons in your JPanel. So now you can access the buttons from the array like this:

```
buttons[i][j];
```